# How do you show concern or kindness to a stranger without being intrusive?

Tags: public-issues, boundaries

I was on the train and a young woman, who was a stranger to me, was sitting in the seat across the aisle from me.  She was clearly in distress, and periodically would begin to cry.  In such a case how should care or concern (kindness) be shown without seeming to be prying into their affairs?  Would a gentle "are you alright?" be appropriate? Would offering a tissue be an option, or might that be too vague a gesture?

Answer (score 33):

I think

> Are you alright?

is fine, but if you feel less confident and wish to couch your language a little more then:

> I don't mean to intrude but I wanted to check you are ok and if there is anything I can do to help

Then make a suggested offer of help: a tissue, a glass of water, someone to talk to, call a family member.

I think it is less direct, as it doesn't ask a question that the person may feel they have to lie to, i.e. saying they are alright when they are obviously not. It gives them an 'out' along the lines of,

> I'll be ok and no there is nothing. But thank you for offering.

I personally think that showing kindness and caring should outweigh impropriety. That we should show caring for others even if it feels socially awkward or there is a social pressure against it - so please go for it and show kindness for someone if it is genuine and deal with the risk of them feeling you are prying. The up-side is you could change someone's life.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer, I think trains offer a special case of stranger interaction.  Many European trains have those six-person rooms, and Amtrak (the US) will seat you with a stranger for dinner.  We're encouraged to talk to each other.  I've had interesting talks with people on trains, I wouldn't want to ignore someone simply because they're having a tough time.

I've also found psychological differences between conversations on the train, and say, random street encounters.  I don't know what it is, maybe being in between here and there, life seems like it's on hold until the train arrives.  An hour-long conversion with someone she'll never see again might be appealing to her.

I agree that "are you alright?" is a good start.  You're making it clear that you see something is up, but also give a good 'out' for her: "I'm alright, just sad".  It could very well be that she's not alright, as in, you need to go get help.